# Group data with windowed functions SQL

Tags: sql-server, distinct, window-functions

Could anyone help me to solve one problem (it's not a problem, but I think of more elegant decision).

I Have a tabale with ProductionResource_id, StartDate, FinishDate. I need to count number of rows, min(StartDate), Max(FinishDate), and AVG in seconds between StartDate and FinishDate. I did a query with subqueries it gave me my desired rows (It was two rows with two PersonID worked in one day) but after hours of execution. I rewrote query with over (partion by):

```
select 
   ProductionResource_id,
   a.FinishDate,
   COUNT(*) over (partition by a.ProductionResource_id) as QuantityOperations,
   avg(datediff(second, a.TaskDate, a.FinishDate) over (partition by 
     a.ProductionResource_id)) as AvgTimeOperations,
   sum(datediff(second, a.TaskDate, a.FinishDate) over (partition by 
     a.productionResource_id)) as SumTimeOperations,
   MIN(a.TaskDate) over (partition by a.productionResource_id) as BeginTimeOperations,
   max(FinishDate) over (partition by a.productionResource_id) as EndTimeOperations
from 
   hdr_MaterialPicking as a with(nolock)
where 
   a.FinishDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
group by 
   a.ProductionResource_id, 
   a.TaskDate,
   a.FinishDate,
   a.BaseQuantity,
   d.UnitKoeff,
   d.NettoWeight,
   d.UnitVolume
order by 1 asc, 2 asc
```

This query executes in one second but returns amount of rows equals to COUNT(*) related to each ProductionResource_Id. And to get my two desired rows I need to use distinct. I don't like queries with distinct so if there a way to rewrite this query avoiding distinct, but perfomance must not be slower then in this query?

Comment: Why go you have a `GROUP BY` when all are your aggregates are windowed? Why are you using `NOLOCK`? Don't order by ordinal, it's a bad habit. `a` is an odd choice of alias for `hdr_MaterialPicking` too. [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal), [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere), [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: I'm confused: do you want the aggregation results grouped or windowed? If you want to group the rows why do you have window aggregates? If you want them windowed (so actually return every row), why do you have `group by`

Comment: I had to use agregate because MS SQL Server gives an error if i ommit one of the fields